# Problems trying to retrieve logs from a Correlation Id

Tags: sharepoint-online, bcs, log

I have a correlation id for an error that an external list has been throwing which I need to view the ULS log entries for. I've connected to the site in SharePoint Online Management Shell using `Connect-SPOService` and then attempted to view the logs using `Get-SPOTenantLogEntry -CorrelationId "my-correlation-id"`.

For some reason this doesn't throw an error, but it also doesn't return any results.

I've then tried to use the code based solution on Vardhaman's blog ([link](http://www.vrdmn.com/2014/03/view-tenant-uls-logs-in-sharepoint.html)) but the `Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.Client.Tenant` assembly appears to no longer be active (the nuget package doesn't support any version of .Net 4.0 onwards).

Assuming I have a correlation Id from an external list and just want to view ULS entries for that error, how do I do it with SharePoint Online?

As per this link: [Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161369.aspx), it seems to be supported for BCS. Why then do I not get any results?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer would be you can't on your own for anyother error apart from BCS. `Get-SPOTenantLogEntry` would return zero results when there are no logs present, though it can be a hit or miss sometimes. Go for a safer approach, recreate the error, wait for few moments and execute below command:

```
$endTimeinUTC = Get-SPOTenantLogLastAvailableTimeInUtc
$startTimeinUTC = $endTimeinUTC.AddDays (-14)
$tenantlogs = Get-SPOTenantLogEntry -StartTimeinUtc $startTimeinUTC -EndTimeinUTC $endTimeinUTC -CorrelationId yourCorrelationId
```

If it doesn't work,`only way to get the root cause is to open a ticket and pray for a timely response.` I found this MS community [question](https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/218041) which will better explain for other error types or even for this as well.

> You can post the detailed Correlation ID to us for help, because the
>   detailed information about the Correlation ID is not opened to the
>   customer. The Correlation ID is the code from server side, which
>   includes detailed error activity logs about when the error occurred,
>   where the error happened, which feature was related to the error and
>   whom suffered the impact. As we consider that the correlation id
>   includes the customer privacy information, this part will be only
>   visible to the Support from the server side. That is why you cannot
>   search the information from the help center.  Therefore, if you
>   receive error messages with the Correlation ID, I suggest you contact
>   us or the other Office 365 support channels (the service tickets) to
>   get the reason as soon as possible. We would like to capture and
>   summarize the error activity logs from the server side, and then
>   explain you the root cause about the Correlation ID by using PM.

Comment: Not true for BCS. Why does he get zero results when it is explicitly mentioned in the documentation that BCS is supported for getting logs? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161369.aspx

Comment: @Taran Goel I'll give it a shot. Quite frustrating that it's all so poorly designed (tell me those no logs, don't just not show anything!) and limited as well...